# from tensorflow import keras ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run a few lines of code using Tensorflow in MacOS M2. I am trying to import keras from TensorFlow but I am getting the same error every time.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

The error that I am getting:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

I tried the below code to debug the issue myself and got the following error:

```
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow import keras
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)

import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras import __internal__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/__internal__/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.__internal__ import backend
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/__internal__/backend/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend import _initialize_variables as initialize_variables
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras.src import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/models/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.src.engine.functional import Functional
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

I have tried almost all the solutions here, like uninstalling and reinstalling Tensorflow, but the issue remains.

Versions:

```
Installing collected packages: keras
Successfully installed keras-2.13.1

pip install tensorflow --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-macos==2.13.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.13.0)

kaiser@Ankurs-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.11.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 'keras' installed separately along with tensorflow. Maybe try to uninstall standalone 'keras' library. Once you uninstall 'keras' you should be able to import using `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`. Hopefully this works.